# How we solve $0=y\sin\frac{3t}{2}+x\cos\frac{3t}{2}-y\sin(t)-x\cos(t)$ for real $t$ ($\frac{4\pi}{3}<t<2\pi$) or at least get the curve's degree?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, algebraic-geometry, curves, algebraic-curves

I have a system of equation:

- $x^2+y^2=y\sin\frac{3t}{2}+x\cos\frac{3t}{2}$
- $x^2+y^2=y\sin(t)+x\cos(t)$

I want to get an algebraic curve depending only from $x$ and $y$. If it is too complex, it would be already sufficient to determine, which degree the resulting curve has.

Can we **at least determine the degree** (the largest power $n$ that appears in $x^n$) of the curve equation in $x$ and $y$?

I am interested only in a (real) range $\frac{4\pi}{3}<t<2\pi$, which hopefully gives a condition that reduces the effort in solving the equation.

Comment: I think that it would be much more simple to use parametric equations $x=f(t)$ and $y=g(t)$. Trying for write $h(x,y)=0$ would probably lead to a monster.

Comment: Correct - I fear too that the polynomial form may end in a monster. I have already this parametric form. But is it at least possible to determine the degree of that monster? For example if the resulting equation looks like $y^3=ax^6+bxy+\ldots$ can we still determine "the degree is $6$"? That would already help a lot.

Comment: Eldar Sultanow - Do you know that these equations are two circles of radius $\frac1{2}$ with centers moving with $t$?

Comment: Yes - geometrically I am guessing that there is a (cardiod-like) envelope behind this system of equation, which indirectly implies such a circle movement.

Comment: In maxima CAS `solve([x^2+y^2-sin((3*t)/2)*y-cos((3*t)/2)*x,x^2+y^2-y*sin(t)-x*cos(t)], [x,y]);` gives a parametrization that implicitizes to $16x^6+48x^4y^2+48x^2y^4+16y^6-20x^4-40x^2y^2-20y^4+5x^2+5y^2-x=0$

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland: Great tool - I was not aware of it. I am using Mathematica and using a similar Solve[] command it gives me an output that is almost unmanageable.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland: How did you transform the parametric form to an implicit one using Maxima Cas? The command solve([]) provides me a large parametrization.

Comment: I used `load(grobner);` `poly_buchberger([c^2+s^2-1,x-(2*c^3+c^2-(3/2)*c-1/2),y-(((1/2)*s)*(4*c^2+2*c-1))],[c,s,x,y]);`

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland: I have a second parametric system of equations:  solve([x^2+y^2+sin((3*t)/4)*y+cos((3*t)/4)*x,x^2+y^2-y*sin(t)-x*cos(t)], [x,y]); How I get using Maxima CAS to the polynomial form (step by step)? I cannot see how you obtain the input for the poly_buchberger function.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland: Ah now I saw it - $s$ stands for $\sin$ and $c$ stands for the $\cos$ terms.

Comment: For this I get `poly_buchberger([c^2+s^2-1, x-4*c^4+2*c^3+4*c^2-(3/2)*c-1/2, y-(1/2)*s*(8*c^3-4*c^2-4*c+1)],[c,s,x,y]);` or $16x^6+48x^4y^2+48x^2y^4+16y^6-20x^4-40x^2y^2-20y^4+5x^2+5y^2-x=0$

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland: One last question: how do you deduce the terms $2*c^3+c^2-(3/2)*c-1/2$? (It is from the first case.) I understand $c$ stands for $\cos(t)$ and $s$ for $\sin(t)$. When I try to transform $cos(t)+cos(3 t/2)$ I obtain something different.

Comment: In maple I used `convert(,exp)` then `simplify()` and `convert(,sincos)`. Then in the first case I get it in terms of $\cos(\frac{t}{2})$ and $\sin(\frac{t}{2})$ and in the second case in terms of $\cos(\frac{t}{4})$ and $\sin(\frac{t}{4}).$ I tried replicating it in maxima CAS with `exponentialize` and `demoivre` without luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already isolated a linear equation in $x$ and $y$ for each value $t$:

$$ y \sin \frac{3t}{2} + x \cos \frac{3t}{2} - y \sin t - x \cos t = 0 $$
$$ y = \frac{\cos t - \cos \frac{3t}{2}}{\sin \frac{3t}{2} - \sin t} x $$
$$ y = m(t) \, x \quad\mathrm{\ where\ } m(t) = \frac{\cos t - \cos \frac{3t}{2}}{\sin \frac{3t}{2} - \sin t} $$

unless $\sin \frac{3t}{2} - \sin t = 0$, which occurs at $t=2\pi m$ and at $t=\frac{2\pi}{5} (2n+1)$ for any integer $m$ or $n$. This never happens in the given domain $\frac{4\pi}{3} < t < 2\pi$.

$$ m(t) = \frac{2 \sin \frac{5t}{4}\, \sin \frac{t}{4}}{2 \cos \frac{5t}{4}\, \sin \frac{t}{4}} $$
$$ m(t) = \tan \frac{5t}{4} $$

Based on this ratio, let's define $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ in terms of the unknown magnitude $r(t)$:

$$ x = r \cos \frac{5t}{4} $$
$$ y = r \sin \frac{5t}{4} $$

Then from the second original equation,

$$ r^2 = r \sin \frac{5t}{4}\, \sin t + r \cos \frac{5t}{4}\, \cos t $$

The solution $r=0$ is just the extra point $(0,0)$ which always satisfies the equations for any $t$. Ignoring that, we can divide out $r$.

$$ r = \cos \left(\frac{5t}{4} - t\right) = \cos \frac{t}{4} $$

So

$$ x = \cos \frac{5t}{4}\, \cos \frac{t}{4} $$
$$ x^2+y^2 = \cos^2 \frac{t}{4} $$

The fifth [Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) is $T_5(z) = 16z^5 - 20z^3+5z$, so

$$ \cos \frac{5t}{4} = T_5\left(\cos \frac{t}{4}\right) = 16 \cos^5 \frac{t}{4} - 20 \cos^3 \frac{t}{4} + 5 \cos \frac{t}{4} $$
$$ x = 16 \cos^6 \frac{t}{4} - 20 \cos^4 \frac{t}{4} + 5 \cos^2 \frac{t}{4} $$
$$ x = 16 (x^2+y^2)^3 - 20 (x^2+y^2)^2 + 5 (x^2+y^2) $$

This is a polynomial equation in just $x$ and $y$ of degree 6.

Comment: Thank you very much for this step-by-step guide, which helps me a lot.